# Dynamically-generated array with MODE.MULT for Chart Series Values causes Excel 2010 to crash

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, dynamic-chart-series

First of all, I would like to clarify that I am looking for a technical explanation as to *why* the following issue occurs, rather than for alternative set-ups which achieve the desired result (I shall in any case present several such alternatives as part of this question).

Also, I have not tested this in versions of Excel other than `Excel 2010`, so am not aware whether this issue is version-specific or not.

```
Row/  B   C
Col     
1     X   91
2     X   96
3     X   21
4     X   64
5          3
6     X   60
7         52
8     X   37
9         79
10        91
```

Assuming all entries are made in `Sheet1`, then given, for example, a series of numerics in the range `C1:C10`, and with each entry in the range `B1:B10` being either "X" or not (example given above), the following construction:

`=INDEX($C:$C,N(IF(1,MODE.MULT(IF($B$1:$B$10="X",{1,1}*ROW($B$1:$B$10))))))`

properly coerced, will generate a vertical array of *n* entries, where *n* is equal to the result of:

`=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,"X")`

This array will comprise the *n* entries from column C whose corresponding entry in column B is "X". For the above example, this construction would return:

`{91;96;21;64;60;37}`

This formula is then entered as a (Workbook-scope) `Defined Name` within `Name Manager`, e.g. with Name `Series_MODE_MULT`. Note that, being a `Defined Name`, the construction is by default evaluated as an `array formula`, and so satisfies the condition of being "properly coerced" which I mentioned earlier.

When attempting to create a simple chart (Column, for example) with a single series, whose `Series Values` are entered as:

`=Sheet1!Series_MODE_MULT`

Excel immediately crashes.

But why?

I have searched for an explanation for some hours now. The only similar cases I can come up with relate to the use of `INDIRECT` within the construction being passed as the Chart's `Series Values`; however, although that too is invalid (we can in fact develop a workaround using `EVALUATE`), the user is met with the error message "*A formula in this worksheet contains one or more invalid references*.", which, of course, is not at all the same as flat-out crashing.

My title suggests that the issue might be specifically related to the function `MODE.MULT`. My reasoning is that we can employ alternative (though longer and, in some cases, volatile) constructions which generate the required array but which are perfectly valid when passed as the Chart's `Series Values`:

`=INDEX($C:$C,N(IF(1,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$10="X",ROW($B$1:$B$10)),ROW(INDEX($A:$A,1):INDEX($A:$A,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,"X")))))))`

or:

`=N(OFFSET($C$1,SMALL(IF($B$1:$B$10="X",ROW($B$1:$B$10)-MIN(ROW($B$1:$B$10))),ROW($A$1:OFFSET($A$1,COUNTIF($B$1:$B$10,"X")-1,))),))`

being just two such examples.

Is `MODE.MULT` somehow responsible here? What makes this construction valid within the worksheet though not within a Chart's `Series Values`? Are there any other constructions/functions which, used in this way, similarly cause Excel to crash? If so, what is the explanation for such behaviour?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Comment: It's easy to reproduce in 2013 and definitely related to MODE.MULT. Defined name `=MODE.MULT(1,1,2,2)` also crashes Excel.

Comment: @BrakNicku Many thanks. Stupidly, I didn't even think to test a construction involving solely MODE.MULT. So it's nothing to do with 'dynamic' ranges at all and purely to do with MODE.MULT.